# How with youtube_dl i can play playlist in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Here is my code of play command

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx, url):   
    try:
        voice_channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        vc = await voice_channel.connect()
    except:
        print('already connected')

    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
    if 'entries' in info:
        video = info['entries'][0]
        if(voice.is_playing()):
            voice.stop()
            voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(video,executable = "C:/Users/Gleb/Desktop/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe", **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
        else:
            voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(video,executable = "C:/Users/Gleb/Desktop/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe", **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
    else:
        URL = info['formats'][0]['url']
        if(voice.is_playing()):
            voice.stop()
            voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(UE,executable = "C:/Users/Gleb/Desktop/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe", **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
        else:
            voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(video,executable = "C:/Users/Gleb/Desktop/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe", **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfVvn.png)

i get an error when i play playlist that the 'video' is a dictionary but it only takes string

Answer (score 0):

Your program won't work like this.
The [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#ffmpegpcmaudio) state that `FFmpegPCMAudio` is declared as

```
class discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source, *, executable='ffmpeg', pipe=False, stderr=None, before_options=None, options=None)
```

You're giving it your dictionary `video` as `source`. However, `FFmpegPCMAudio()` is not capable of buffered video streaming. It can only play locally saved files, which are converted to audio by `FFmpeg`. `source` has to be the link to a file, just like you have in the argument `executable`. And since you have the argument `download = False` in

```
info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
```

you're only extraction video-information, but not actually downloading it. If there is no file, you can't play it.

---

To solve your problem, you will need to download the audio of the youtube video, and give `FFmpegPCMAudio()` the filepath as `source`